# Trying to make a portable Mac Pro.

Tags: macbook-pro, mac, mac-pro

Is there a third party way to use a Mac Pro as the "computer" and a laptop as the Screen, mouse, keyboard, speaker, ext?

Comment: `System preferences > Sharing > Screen Sharing` might be good enough.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it **might** work but in taking about target display mode Apple only mentions an iMac as supported.

[Target Display Mode](http://support.apple.com/kb/PH14264)

Though they do not specifically mention a MacBook as supported or not. It is unlikely that trying it would cause problems (or damage), but I am unsure.